# AWS dynamoDB: read capacity calculated/applied before or after the filter?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

AWS DynamoDB allows table scans that include filters. Is the read capacity calculated/applied before or after the filter?

Example: lets say I have a 16KB table (with 4 items each 4 KB) = with a read capacity of 1 unit (allowing 4KB per second).  The table is scanned to find the one row that matches a filter expression.  Only one row is returned to the client.  Does this operation use only 1 unit of read (because only 4 KB is returned to the client), or does this scan go over my capacity because the read units are calculated before the filter is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that DynamoDB allows small peeks of charge, it **should** be ok even with your 1 RCU set for the table as long as you do not abuse the feature.

Read here [about scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html):

> A FilterExpression is applied **after the items have already been read**; the process of filtering does not consume any additional read capacity units.

**And here is your answer from [AWS Working with Scans page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html)**

> A filter expression is applied after a Scan finishes, but before the results are returned. Therefore, a Scan will consume the same amount of read capacity, regardless of whether a filter expression is present.

*(edited)* So, you'll pay <strike>4 RCU</strike> more than one 1 RCU.

Comment: If scanning with eventual consistency, the 16kb scan will only consume 2 RCU.